# dynamicBullets is not supported in ionic-slides?

Tags: ionic-framework, swiper.js, ion-slides

dynamicBullets is not supported in ionic-slides?
ionic-slides adopted from swiper.js and swiper.js support dynamicBullets: boolean.

How can I use dynamicBullets in ionic-slides?

I even tried to inject swiper.js into the ionic project and it's not working well. I believe there is a conflict error somewhere in ionic since it was adopted from swiper.js

Answer (score -1):

I am using this to add bullets in text line. try this

```
<ul> 
  <li><p>Keep your knees and tons pointing slightly outwards as you jump.</p> 
  </li>
  <li><p>Land with soft knees on the balls of your feet to protect your knees.</p></li>
  <li><p>Go as fast as you can without losing control.</p></li>
</ul>
```